# Is it possible to find the function whose ranges the sum of 2 different functions' ranges?

Tags: functions

Suppose    $ f: f(n)→  D'f $ and $ g:  g(n)→D'g $ , $ n \in ℕ $

Is it possible to find $ h: h(n)→(D'f ∪ D'g)$ ?

For example, we have $ Un=2n-1, \ n \in ℕ  $ , whose range is $ {1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,...} $
and $ Vn=4n,\ n \in ℕ $ , whose range is $ {4,8,12,16...} $

Is there a function $ Wn $ whose range is $ {1,3,4,5,7,8,9,11,12,13,15,16} $ and is here a way to find it?

Comment: Your question and your notation are rather too telegraphic. Could you explain more fully?

Comment: @Lubin I  edited the post with an example.

Comment: Ah, I see. You have used the word “domain” differently than most people. Nowadays, the set of values that the function takes on is usually called the “range” of the function. I think you also want to specify that the set on which your desired function is defined must be $\Bbb N$ in all cases.

Comment: Yeah, you're right I mixed the two... But still, with all the errors aside and hopefully more clearly, can you answer my question?

Comment: Those are more than minor errors.  I'd say the entire question needs to be rewritten as "range" (output image) is the exact *opposite* of "domain" (input). Anyway there are an infinite number of functions with that range.  Just make up any function you want.  If you mean any function that will be the same range and compatible with the functions.  Well, there would be but not for your example where $Un(k) = 2k-1 \ne Wn(k) = 4k$.

Comment: What exacty do you think a "function" is?  For any range there are an infinite number of functions with the range.  Just assign anything you want to anything you want.  Just say $h(n) = $ the n-th number in 1,3,4,5,7,8.9......  $h(n) = f(n/2)$ if $n$ is even and $h(n) =g((n-1)/2$ if $n $ is odd.  Or h(n) = f(n without the last digit) if n ends with 7, and h(n)= g(n without the last digit) if n ends with 3, and h(n)= 13 if n ends with anything other than 3 or 7.  Or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Let $h(n) = f(\lfloor n/100 \rfloor)$ if $n \equiv 63 \mod 100$ but $h(n) = g(\lfloor n/100 \rfloor)$ if $n \equiv 17 \mod 100$ but $h(n) = g(f(g(g(f(926)))))$ if $n \not \equiv 63 \mod 100$ or $n \not \equiv 17 \mod 100$ will have a range of $D'f \cup D'g$